# ffmpeg prores alpha channel quantization looks pretty bad

Tags: ffmpeg, prores, alpha

Might be related to [this other ticket](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20024)?

I've been doing some prores tests for both color and alpha.  Usually this isn't a big deal since my alpha channels are solid with a 1-2pixel transition to black.  However I did some tests with a very gradual change in alpha value over many pixels and noticed some pretty bad alpha channel quantization with the prores_ks encoder.  The Apple prores spec says for 4444(XQ) the alpha channel is 16bit and lossless so this is quite different from that.  I've attached a comparison image.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 24.0 -i tif/rgba_16bit.%3d.tif -filter_complex "[0]colorspace=all=bt709:range=pc:format=yuv444p12:iall='bt601-6-625':irange=pc[main];[0]alphaextract,format=gray16le[alpha];[main][alpha]alphamerge" -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 5 -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -alpha_bits 16 prores4444XQ_yuva.mov
```

Image below is actually 8bit due to imgur limitations so the 16bit and 10bit examples aren't really correct but you get the point.

Also it looks like `-alpha_bits 8` and `-alpha_bits 16` produce the same look so maybe its getting bad upstream?

[image: alpha quantization]

Comment: It migth be that just because you use XQ profile.

Comment: Just checked with `profile:v 4` which is regular 4444 and it still looks like that :(